# Scikit-learn: Calculate likelihood based on multiple test samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn to build a GMM classifier. For testing I use a file X which contains a large number of rows, each row represents a feature vector [x,y,z].

For example:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,2,3]
[4,4,5]
...
```

I assign each row a corresponding class label. When I use the scikit-learn score() function, it calculates the log probabilities of each data point in X. For my application this is not very useful because each test sample in my file represents a motion frame and recognition based on a single frame is not accurate. Instead, I would like to use a larger number of frames (samples) for testing and calculate the log likelihood on the basis of the group of samples rather than a single sample. This way I could recognize a person by looking at 30 seconds of their motion rather than looking at a very short single time frame. 
Is this possible with scikit-learn and how can I accomplish this?

Comment: This seems like an HMM formulation, instead of GMM. You should try to reformulate the problem.

Comment: I still make the simple and not very intuitive GMM assumption that features are independent of each other. Still I'd like to look at several feature vectors at once, let's say I accumulate 3 feature vectors into one larger feature vector with 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Then you should flatten each feature matrix to a row (```reshape``` in numpy). As long as all have same length, it is good to be considered a feature.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. If I do that I have to flatten the training data array as well. But the training data has to be arranged into as many columns as there are in the array of means, i.e. 3 in the above case. Otherwise scikit learn returns a value error. I don't know if it's a sensible idea to flatten the array of means too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to take various rows or "motion frames" and amalgamate them into a numeric representation before running through an estimator? So from your example of:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,2,3]
[4,4,5]
```

You might want a final representations such as count1, count2, count3 of differences or progressions in directionality from state_0 to state_n. Given the example data a final step might be 3,2,2 as that's the difference from the final state and the beginning state. This does not capture fluctuation or variance expressed along the way however, take data like this:

```
[1,2,3]
[10,6,1]
[3,3,5]
[1,0,6]
[2,2,2]
```

The final metric would be 1,0,1 which does not convey or capture any of the fluctuation. Are you allowed to use covariance matrices are use a variance column/feature wise?

You could consider examining statistics using your example of 30 frames (rows/observations):

```
>> import numpy as np 
>>> data = np.array([
...     [1, 2, 3],
...     [2 ,2, 3],
...     [4, 4, 5],
...     ...........
...     [3, 3, 3]])
>>> np.argmax(np.var(data, axis=1)) #var, mean, std, etc
```